# Does singing about certain things offend gods?

Tags: sin, life, chandra, soma

For example, does singing about the Moon, or a sing with lyrics referring to the Moon, offend Soma, the Lord of the Moon?

EDIT: I wish to specify that I do not mean a song sung in praise or worship, but rather a casual song from a secular source, not religious. Like, from a film or an album.

Answer (score 2):

Singing is a mode for appeasing the deities. If you are praising through your singing there is no reason the deity will get offended.

Usually people know about the 5 Upachara Puja or even the 16 Upachara Puja. But sometimes Pujas are done more elaborately where 32 Upacharas (instead of 16) are offered for pleasing the deity.

Quoting from [Astrojyoti](https://www.astrojyoti.com/shodasaupacharas-2.htm):

> A Vedic ritual is never a meaningless act. Each and every one of them
> has a deep rooted spiritual philosophic significance.
>
> A more elaborate Pooja will include the 32 upacharas. They are as
> follows:
>
> Aavahanam, Asanam, padyam, Arghyam, Acamanam, Madhuparkam, Snanam,
> Vastam, Upavitam, Abharanam, Gandham, Akshatam, Pushpam, Dhuupam,
> Deepam, Naivedyam, Tambulam, Daxina, Phalam, Nirajanam, Pushpanjalim,
> Pradaxinam, Namaskaram, Stotram, Chatram, Chaamara, Vahanam,
> **Nrityam, Gitam,** Vaadyam, Prarthanam, Visarjanam with mantra pushpam and shanti patham.

So, dancing (Nrityam) and singing (Gitam) are Upacharas which when offered the deity gets pleased. Such lists of 32 Upcharas are found in texts like Brihat Tantrasara.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I must have specified that I meant not songs sung in praise or worship, but rather casual songs, like a film song or from an album, or any other from a secular source, not religious.

Comment: @Seeker I think you must have forgotten to specify, before the answer was written. The edit thereafter gives clarity.

Comment: Nothing on that topic will be found in scriptures .. but if songs contain the name of deities in not an offensive way then deities will not get offended because taking the names of deities is also an act that gives merit. @Seeker

Comment: @Rickross I thank you again, but that is precisely why I asked the question. I do not know if the songs I hear on a daily basis are offensive or not. Your bio states that you are from India, too, so I imagine you would know the songs we tend to hear in films and albums.

Comment: I am not sure if in songs they really say something offensive about the Moon god or other deities but I don't think it is anything to worry about @Seeker